# How do I merge three columns into two, One categorical and the other numerical? (python pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-science

Data Science intern here.

Okay so I currently have a dataframe in python that looks like:

```
        df = pd.DataFrame({'Utility': ["Akron", 'Akron', 'Akron', 'Akron'],
                           'Area': ['other', 'other', 'other', 'other'], 
                           'Category': ['Digital', 'Digital', 'Digital', 
                            'Digital'], 
                           'Subcategory': ['Plans', 'Services', 'Asset 
                            Management', 'Billing'], 
                           'Unit':['USD','USD','USD','USD'], 
                           'Value':[0,0,0,0], 
                           "Population Served": 
                           [280000,280000,280000,280000]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Utility   Area Category       Subcategory Unit  Value  Population Served
0   Akron  other  Digital             Plans  USD      0             280000
1   Akron  other  Digital          Services  USD      0             280000
2   Akron  other  Digital  Asset Management  USD      0             280000
3   Akron  other  Digital           Billing  USD      0             280000
```

My supervisor says she needs to be able to filter the column units in order to find both the Value and Population Served columns. So she wants the Unit column to contain both categories: (Population Served and USD) and the Value column to simply have either the population of the given Utility, or the spend. Note: I guess she wants all the category columns (Area, Category, Subcategory, etc.) to be blank for any row that is indicating the Population Served by a given utility.

So I need it to look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Utility': ["Akron", 'Akron', 'Akron', 'Akron', 
                              "Akron", 'Akron', 'Akron', 'Akron'], 
                   'Area': ['other', 'other', 'other', 'other', np.nan, 
                            np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Category': ['Digital', 'Digital', 'Digital', 
                   'Digital', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   'Subcategory': ['Plans', 'Services', 'Asset 
                   Management', 'Billing', np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 
                   'Unit':['USD','USD','USD','USD', 'Pop Served', 'Pop 
                            Served', 'Pop Served', 'Pop Served'], 
                   'Value':[0,0,0,0,280000,280000,280000,280000]})
```

print(df)

Output:

```
      Utility   Area Category       Subcategory        Unit   Value
0   Akron  other  Digital             Plans         USD       0
1   Akron  other  Digital          Services         USD       0
2   Akron  other  Digital  Asset Management         USD       0
3   Akron  other  Digital           Billing         USD       0
4   Akron    NaN      NaN               NaN  Pop Served  280000
5   Akron    NaN      NaN               NaN  Pop Served  280000
6   Akron    NaN      NaN               NaN  Pop Served  280000
7   Akron    NaN      NaN               NaN  Pop Served  280000
```

I've been trying to accomplish this with pd.melt, but I can't figure out how to, since I'm dealing with 3 columns being made into two. I'm willing to do this with for loops, but I fear that that may take far too long, and requires precise indexing when inserting new rows.

To be clear, I do not think this is a good idea. I think it doubles the size of the file for no real good reason. I will also accept as an answer on how to accomplish the view she wants within excel, without me having to play with the csv.

Comment: Always provide sample data in text form and also an expected output so people can work on it.

Comment: @HenryYik Okay, I edited the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell apart values in different rows, I defined the source DataFrame as:

```
  Utility   Area Category       Subcategory Unit  Value  Population Served
0   Akron  other  Digital             Plans  USD      0             280100
1   Akron  other  Digital          Services  USD     10             280200
2   Akron  other  Digital  Asset Management  USD     20             280300
3   Akron  other  Digital           Billing  USD     30             280400
```

To get your result, run the following code:

```
wrk = df.drop(columns=['Unit']).rename(columns={'Value': 'USD'})\
    .set_index(df.columns[:4].to_list()).stack().rename('Value')
wrk.index.rename('Unit', level=4, inplace=True)
result = wrk.sort_index(level=4, sort_remaining=False).reset_index()
result.loc[result.Unit == 'Population Served', df.columns[1:4].to_list()] = np.nan
```

The result, for my source data, is:

```
  Utility   Area Category       Subcategory               Unit   Value
0   Akron  other  Digital             Plans                USD       0
1   Akron  other  Digital          Services                USD      10
2   Akron  other  Digital  Asset Management                USD      20
3   Akron  other  Digital           Billing                USD      30
4   Akron    NaN      NaN               NaN  Population Served  280100
5   Akron    NaN      NaN               NaN  Population Served  280200
6   Akron    NaN      NaN               NaN  Population Served  280300
7   Akron    NaN      NaN               NaN  Population Served  280400
```

To fully comprehend how the above code works, run is stepwise (one method
after another) and see the partial results.

Maybe you should also read documentation concerning methods used.

## Edit

An alternative using *melt*:

```
result = df.drop(columns=['Unit']).rename(columns={'Value': 'USD'})\
    .melt(id_vars=['Utility', 'Area', 'Category', 'Subcategory'],
        value_vars=['USD', 'Population Served'], var_name='Unit',
        value_name='Value')
result.loc[result.Unit == 'Population Served', df.columns[1:4].to_list()] = np.nan
```

Comment: Hey @Valdi_Bo If I were to repeat the above method for 486,000 rows, would I replace the number 4 with the number of rows?

Comment: Not. "4" is not the number of rows. It is the number of the index level. And *df.columns[:4]* I used to avoid literal repeating source column names.